# Pagination not working in wordpress / using php

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, pagination

I'm running into an issue where my pagination isn't working on the front end of my site. Every number seems to always direct to page 1. Site can be found here: https://www.ohiostatetaxblog.com/

I'm using Wordpress theme editor and the template is a blog template. My coded template is below. Can anyone help? Maybe I'm just missing something in the code.

```
<?php
    //Template Name: Blog

    get_header();

    global $post;
    if ($post) {
        $slug = get_post($post->ID)->post_name;
    } else {
        $slug = 'no-slug';
    } ?>
<div class="c-attorney_info_wrapper">
    <div class="c-attorney_info u-display_inline_block u-background_color_secondary t-color">
        <div class="c-header c-attorney_header">
            <?php if ( (isset($_GET['category-news']) && $_GET['category-news'] == 1) || (isset($_GET['category-press-releases']) && $_GET['category-press-releases'] == 1) ) { ?>
                <h1 class="t-header t-article_headline t-color_quinary">
                        In The News
                </h1>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <br />
            <?php } ?>
      <?php
            $categories = wp_list_categories("title_li=&echo=0&exclude=4");
        $categories = preg_replace('/ cat-item-[0-9]+/', '', $categories);
            $categories = str_replace('<li class="cat-item">', '', $categories);
        $categories = explode('</li>', $categories);
        $drop = array_pop($categories); ?>

            <script>
        <?php
            echo 'var cats = [';
                  foreach($categories as $category) {
                        //$category = strip_tags($categories);

                if(($pos = strpos($category, '>')) !== false)
                {
                   $category = substr($category, $pos + 1);
                }

                $category = str_replace('</a>', '', $category);
                $category = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $category );
                $category = strtolower((string)$category);

                          echo "'".$category."',";

                  }

                  echo '];'

                  ?>

              function matchCats(input) {
                if(input) {
                  var reg = new RegExp(input.split('').join('\\w*').replace(/\W/, ""), 'i');
                  return cats.filter(function(cat) {
                    if (cat.match(reg)) {
                      return cat;
                    }
                  });
                } else {
                  return '';
                }
              }

              function convertToSlug(Text) {
                  return Text
                      .toLowerCase()
                      .replace(/ /g,'-')
                      .replace(/[^\w-]+/g,'');
              }

              function changeInput(val) {
                var autoCompleteResult = matchCats(val);

                var text = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML;

                autoCompleteResult = autoCompleteResult.toString();
                autoCompleteResult = autoCompleteResult.replace(/,/ig,'<li class="result-list-item">');

                console.log(autoCompleteResult.length);

                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = '<ul id="result-list"><li class="result-list-item">'+autoCompleteResult+'</li></ul>';

                var li = document.getElementsByClassName('result-list-item');

                for(var i = 0; i < li.length; ++i) {
                  if(li[i]) {
                    li[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                      var inpt = document.getElementsByName('category_name');
                        //this.innerHTML;

                        inpt[0].value = this.innerHTML;
                        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = '';
                        document.getElementById("category_name").value = convertToSlug(this.innerHTML);



                      }, false);
                  }
                }


              }

            /*  var li = document.getElementsByClassName('result-list-item');

              for(var i = 0; i < li.length; ++i) {
                if(li[i]) {
                  li[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                      console.log('Hello');
                    }, false);
                }
              }*/



            </script>
            <style>
            form {
                position: relative;
            }
             form .input_wrapper {
                 width: 257px;
                 display: inline-block;
                 vertical-align: top;
             }
               .page-template-blog .c-attorney_info form .input_wrapper input {
                   background: rgb(255,255,255);
                   cursor: text;
               }

            form #result {
          /*position: absolute;
          width: 100%;
          right: 44px;
          top: 35px;*/
          position: relative;
          z-index: 100;
          max-width: 257px;
          background: rgb(255,255,255);
          color: rgb(70,70,72);
          text-transform: uppercase;
          padding: 2px 5px;
          max-height: 257px;
          text-align: left;
          border-top: 1px solid rgba(70,70,72,.2);
            }
             form #result li {
                 cursor: pointer;
             }
               form #result li:hover {
                   background: rgba(70,70,72,.2);
               }
            </style>

            <form action="<?php bloginfo('url').'/category/'; ?>" method="get">
                <form action="<?php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="get">
                <div class="input_wrapper">
                    <input type="text" name="category_name" placeholder="SEARCH BY CATEGORY" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="changeInput(this.value)"/>
                    <div id="result"></div>
                    </div>
            <input id="category_name" type="hidden" name="category_name" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post" />
            <!--<input type="hidden" name="category_name" value="blog" />-->
            <input type="hidden" name="post_status" value="publish" />
                    <input type="submit" value="" onclick="">
                </form>
            </form>

            <p>If you have any questions pertaining to any of these blog posts,
                please fill out our <a href="/contact">Contact Form</a>
            </p>

            <?php echo $post->post_content; ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.c-attorney_info -->

    <div class="c-attorney_photo u-display_inline_block"
            <?php if ( (isset($_GET['category-news']) && $_GET['category-news'] == 1) || (isset($_GET['category-press-releases']) && $_GET['category-press-releases'] == 1) ) { ?>
                style="background: url(/wp-content/themes/ostb/_assets/images/pen-header.jpg) center center no-repeat; background-size: cover;"
            <?php } else { ?>
                style="background: url(/wp-content/themes/ostb/_assets/images/GettyImages-1053768312.jpg) center center no-repeat; background-size: cover;"
            <?php } ?>
            >
    </div>
</div>


<?php

    $page = get_query_var('paged') * 6;
    if (get_query_var('paged') == 0) {
        $page = 0;
    } else {
        $page = (get_query_var('paged') - 1) * 6;

    }

    $pageNum = get_query_var('paged');


        $args = array
        (
                'posts_per_page'   => 6,
                'offset'           => $page,
                'category'         => '',
                'category_name'    => '',
                'orderby'          => 'date',
                'order'            => 'DESC',
                'include'          => '',
                'exclude'          => '',
                'meta_key'         => '',
                'meta_value'       => '',
                'post_type'        => 'post',
                'post_mime_type'   => '',
                'post_parent'      => '',
                'author'           => '',
                'post_status'      => 'publish',
                'suppress_filters' => true,
                'paged'            => $pageNum,
                'cat'              => '',
        );


    $posts = query_posts($args);

    //      CHECK FOR POSTS IN CATEGORY
    if ($posts) { ?>
<div class="c-blog-content">

    <nav class="c-blog-index-nav">
        <?php bdb_blog_index_pagination(); ?>
    </nav>
    <?php foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <?php $external_link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_url', true); ?>
        <div class="c-blog-post-excerpt">
            <?php
                $embed_url = get_post_youtube_link($post->post_content);
                if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                    //the_post_thumbnail();
                } else {
                    //echo '<img src="/wp-content/themes/ostb/_assets/images/BDB_default_blog_image.jpg">';
                }

                if ($external_link) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $external_link; ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo post_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
                <?php } ?>

            <h3><?php the_date(); ?></h3>

            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

            <p><?php the_tags('', ', '); ?></p>

            <?php if ($embed_url) { ?>
                <iframe src="<?php echo $embed_url; ?>" style="width: 100%; height: 250px; margin-top: 20px;"></iframe>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <nav class="c-blog-index-nav">
        <?php bdb_blog_index_pagination(); ?>
    </nav>

    <?php } //      IF NO POST THEN ERROR MESSAGE
        else {
        $args = array
        (
                'posts_per_page'   => 4,
                'category'         => '',
                'category_name'    => '',
                'orderby'          => 'meta_value_num',
                'order'            => 'DESC',
                'include'          => '',
                'exclude'          => '',
                'meta_key'         => '',
                'meta_value'       => '',
                'post_type'        => 'post',
                'post_mime_type'   => '',
                'post_parent'      => '',
                'author'           => '',
                'post_status'      => 'publish',
                'suppress_filters' => true,
                'paged'            => $pageNum,
                'cat'              => '-57, -58, -59',
        );


        $posts = query_posts($args);

        if ($posts) { ?>

    <div class="post-not-found-message">
        <h2>Sorry, No Blog Results Match Your Search Entry.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="top-post-header">
        <h2>Here Are The Top 4 Viewed Posts</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="c-blog-content">

        <?php foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <div class="c-blog-post-excerpt">
                <?php
                    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                        the_post_thumbnail();
                    } else {
                        echo '<img src="/wp-content/themes/ostb/_assets/images/BDB_default_blog_image.jpg">';
                    }
                ?>
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

                <h3><?php the_date(); ?></h3>

                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

                <p><?php the_tags('', ', '); ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php }
            } ?>

    </div>


    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: _"Every number seems to always direct to page 1."_ - that does not appear to be what's happening on the live site you mentioned; https://www.ohiostatetaxblog.com/page/2/ does not show me the same content as the first page again, but instead it shows an _error page_ saying "There has been a critical error on this website."

Comment: If you are using this as a "static front page", then the parameter needs to be named differently, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters - `page` vs `paged`

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your loop, you must make sur to also call wp_reset_postdata();
Also, include the code in a file called archive-{your_custom_post_type}.php and don't forget to enable 'Has Archives' if you are using CPT UI Plugin for your custom post type.

```
<?php

get_header(); ?>


<style>
// simple style for pagination inline
.page-links {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px -2px -4px;
}

.page-numbers {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 32px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 0 13px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    max-width: 40px;
    max-height: 40px;
    color: #000!important;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin: 2px;
}
</style>

<div class="section">

  </div>
</div>

<div class="boxes">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mt-5 px-0">

      <?php 
      $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
      $args = array(
        'post_type'=>'Your_Post_Type', // Your post type name
        'posts_per_page' => 24, // make sure it match wordpress number of posts not to create 404 error archive pages
        'paged' => $paged,
        );

      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
      if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
      ?>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3 p-3 img-overlay">
          <img class="image img-fluid" src="<?php the_field('etudiant_image'); ?>" alt="img">
          <a class="overlay" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="black-txt">
              <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

            </div>
          </a>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile;

        $total_pages = $loop->max_num_pages;

        if ($total_pages > 1){

          $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
          echo' <div class="col-12 text-center pt-2">';

          echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_text'    => __('<'),
            'next_text'    => __('>'),
          ));
          echo' </div>';
        }  
      }

      wp_reset_postdata();
      ?> 

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: The site is giving the error that there's been a critical error on the site, even when implementing the new code. The pages go to the correct pages now but there's an error now. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Make sure 'posts_per_page' => 24, match with the number of posts added in wordpress settings. In your case it would need to be modified for 6 in the code and wp.